# How can I get URL parameter in a jquery ready function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
window.location.href='http://target.SchoolID/set?text=';
});
```

So if someone comes to a page with the above mentioned code using a url like:

Somepage.php?id=abc123

I want the text variable in the ready function to read: abc123

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you don't need jQuery. you can do this with plain JS

```
function getParameterByName( name ) //courtesy Artem
{
  name = name.replace(/[\[]/,"\\\[").replace(/[\]]/,"\\\]");
  var regexS = "[\\?&]"+name+"=([^&#]*)";
  var regex = new RegExp( regexS );
  var results = regex.exec( window.location.href );
  if( results == null )
    return "";
  else
    return decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
```

and then you can just get the querystring value like this:

`alert(getParameterByName('text'));`

also look here for other ways and plugins: [How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/get-querystring-with-jquery)

Comment: Added another answer.  If you feel like it update your answer and i will delete mine.  Thanks for the helpful code.

Answer (score 3):

check out the answer to this questions:
[How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/get-querystring-with-jquery)

that'll give you the value of the id parameter from the query string.

then you can just do something like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var theId = getParameterByName( id)
    var newPath = 'http://target.SchoolID/set?text=' + theId
    window.location.href=newPath;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To help people coming after me that want to have multiple variables and to enhance Moin's answer here is the code for multiple variables:

```
function getParameterByName( name ) //courtesy Artem
{
  name = name.replace(/[\[]/,"\\\[").replace(/[\]]/,"\\\]");
  var regexS = "[\\?&]"+name+"=([^&#]*)";
  var regex = new RegExp( regexS );
  var results = regex.exec( window.location.href );
  if( results == null )
    return "";
  else
  {
    if ((results[1].indexOf('?'))>0)
        return decodeURIComponent(results[1].substring(0,results[1].indexOf('?')).replace(/\+/g, " "));
    else
        return decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
  }
}
```